# How to set up a staging environment based on a symlink to prod configuration, without showing debug information?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I would like to setup a `staging` environment with the same configuration as the `prod` environment.

According to [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#creating-a-new-environment), I proceed as follow:

I create a `staging` symlink that points on `prod`

- configure the env in .env: `APP_ENV=staging`
- clear the cache: `php bin/console cache:clear`
- ask for an URL that does not exist to trigger a 404 error: http://localhost:8080/an-url-that-does-not-exists

When the `APP_ENV=prod`, my custom error page is render properly, but when `APP_ENV=staging`, the debug message `NotFoundHttpException` is rendered?
The profiler is not displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **tldr**;

Crate an `.env.staging` file and use it to set `APP_DEBUG` to `0`. Debug mode and environment are set independently.

---

By default, unless you set it explicitly debug mode (`APP_DEBUG`) is set from the environment automagically.

This happens in the following steps:

In your front-controller (`index.php`, usually) you would find this line:

```
(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

And on `DotEnv::bootEnv()` you'll find this:

```
$debug = $_SERVER[$k] ?? !\in_array($_SERVER[$this->envKey], $this->prodEnvs, true);
```

This will compare your `APP_ENV` with an array of "environments" that `DotEnv`, considers "production-like". By default, this array includes only `prod`.

You could modify the instance of the `DotEnv` by calling `setProdEnvs()`:

```
(new Dotenv())
    ->setProdEnvs(['prod', 'staging'])
    ->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

... but generally simply disabling debug mode on your `.env` file would be enough.

Comment: perfect answer, this is what I was looking for. Thanks @yivi.